# memory usage of virtual machine more than setting

Tags: windows-7, memory, virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware

host:win7 8GRAM
guest:win7 1GRAM

I tried both on VirtualBox and vmware

when guest stop, the free memory of host is 4G~6G

when guest running but "nothing" is working in guest, the free memory of host is 3G~5G

when the guest is working(like windows update), the memory of host left only 100M~1G, and every operation in host is very slow.

and then, I power off the guest, the free memory of host is back to 4G~6G, and no slow motion immediately

I can't figure out the memory usage of virtual machine.

thanks for any reply

Comment: From where are you reading the RAM available, specifically the "100~1G" value?

Comment: @RandolphWest : I read the RAM available from Windows Task Manager and another software can list the system resources

Comment: When you run the guest, what is the usage of RAM inside the VM? Does it respect your 1GB limit?

Comment: @RandolphWest I only run windows update in guest. And the guest also has free RAM(windows task manager).For the convenience of explanation， I increase the guest RAM to 2G, and now only windows update is running, the memory available in task manager is about 1G. memory available in host is also 800M

Comment: Do you have a CPU that supports VT-x, and have you enabled the virtualization features in your BIOS?

Comment: @Zoredache thx, I checked the option of virtual machine, unchecked virtual vt-x option, then the memory of guest is limit as it's setting.